# Is it possible to contact a user

Tags: discussion

If I were interested in contacting one specific user in stackoverflow, would it then be possible ?

If so, how to do that ?

Is there like a chat function in here, or is it possible to send this user a mail to his inbox ?

Ola

Comment: SO is not about users, it's about posts, so the only way to do this is dropping into chat in a room they're in. Also, this should be on Meta.